# elevatezoom not working after add runat="server"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="Images/org_chart/admin.jpg"  data-zoom-image="Images/org_chart/admin.jpg" width="700" height="700"  />

<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My code is working fine,the image able to zoom in when mouse hover.
After i add in runat="server" in my img tag,it fail to zoom in.

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="Images/org_chart/admin.jpg"  data-zoom-image="Images/org_chart/admin.jpg" width="700" height="700" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Why do you want to add runat="server"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendered client id wont match server id. To get rendered id use:
[Control.ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<script>
    $("#<%= zoom_01.ClientID %>").elevateZoom();
</script>
```